# React Native Async Axios not responding

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, expo

I've got JWT logging and I'm trying to get the user by token

```
export const authTokenLogin = async (token) => {
  let extra_url = `jwttokenlogin`;
  try {
    console.log("Break Point 1");
    const response_user = await Axios.post(BASE_URL + extra_url, null, {
      params: {
        token,
      },
    });

    console.log(response_user.data);
    return response_user.data;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Break Point 2");
    console.log(e.response.status);
    return null;
  }
};
```

all worked fine until few days ago from reason yet to be discovered

now it gets to "Break Point 1" and stock there, not reaching "Break Point 2" or "Break Point 3"
just stock and heat up my phone

I've manage to get the token from

```
export const authLogin = async (email, password, rememberMe) => {
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("email", email);
  formData.append("password", password);
  formData.append("remember_me", rememberMe);
  try {
    return await Axios.post(BASE_URL + "jwtlogin", formData).then((res) => {
      return res.data.data;
    });
  } catch (e) {
    return e.response.status;
  }
};
```

So the server is alive and responding

looking for solution , Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that token is not working anymore ? or where the problem exactly ?

Comment: The problem is that I'm not getting any answer or error.
The token works in postman @HassanKandil

Comment: try adding headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }

Comment: Do you have any axios interceptor configured that may be hung?

Comment: it doesn't  help  @HassanKandil

Comment: no, I don't @Atmas